# Can't get ForEach loop to function with nested JSON data in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui

I'm trying to create a list using a `ForEach` on contacts within my service model data.

The model is as below;

```
struct ServiceContract: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
    let maplogo: String
    let customerName: String
    let postcode: String
    let serviceCompany: String
    let projectNumber: Int
    let renewalDate: String
    let contractTerm: Int
    let annualValue: Double
    let paymentTerms: String
    let relationship: String
    let geuOEM: String
    let additionalSpendToDate: Double
    let type: String
    let contacts: Contacts
    let service: [String]
    let notes: String
    
    // Computer Property
    var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }
}

struct Contacts: Codable {
    let contact: [Contact]
}

struct Contact: Codable {
    let contactFirstName: String
    let contactLastName: String
    let contactNumber: String
    let contactEmailAddress: String
}
```

So basically each service contract (that does conform to `Identifiable`) can have multiple contacts. This is achieved by utilising a couple of extra structs.

So to the problem. I want to simply create a list of each contact for a particular service contract, but I cannot get the `ForEach` to function, as using the `\.id` doesn't work, and I can't use the `serviceContract.contacts.contact` as this does not conform to `Identifiable`.

Extract of code below:

```
VStack {
    ForEach(serviceContract.contacts.contact) { cont in
        Text("\(cont.contactFirstName)")
    } //: LOOP
}
```

Comment: Can you make `Contact` to conform to `Identifiable`, for instance by using `contactNumber` as the `id`?

Comment: Even simpler might be to provide an id parameter in the `ForEach` initializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each contact in `serviceContract.contacts` must be unique. If `contactNumber` is unique then you can do this

```
ForEach(serviceContract.contacts.contact, id: \.self.contactNumber)
```

If none of the fields in `Contact` are unique, then you can make the whole `Contact` conform to `Hashable` (this will require some additional code), and then use the whole `Contact` instance as the identifier:

```
ForEach(serviceContract.contacts.contact, id: \.self)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and prompt reply.